# jQuery: extend a $.fn.func to $.func - stateful

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have written a plugin function,

```
$.fn.xyz = function(options) {
...
}
```

I'm able to call this on elements, like this,

```
$('.eleClass').xyz();
```

But what I want is to be able to call my xyz without passing any selector, ie.,

```
$.xyz();
```

ie., I basically want to overload my existing `xyz` to work for both `$(selector).xyz({a:A,b:B,c:C})` and `$.xyz({a:A})`

Comment: what is a reasoning behind having **both** of these working? and what have you tried,. by the way?

Comment: I have written a modal plugin, It can work in 2 ways, if you call it on an element,`$(selector).xyz({a:A})` it will put the element in the modal, if you call it by just passing a url,`$.xyz({url:'/a/bcd.php'})` it should display the output in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

It should be directly written as this.

```
$.xyz = function(options) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement both way you can check the length of `this`.

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/2BAep/

Comment: @A.Wolff That did it, Thanks, But is this the right way to do it?

Comment: this is one way of doing it. You could extend jquery object (usually preferred method) like this: `$.extend($, {
        xyz: $.fn.xyz
    });` http://jsfiddle.net/sVff3//